# How to allow a worker thread to update an X11 Window?

Tags: c++, x11

I have an application that that I was trying to modify so that a worker thread can tell a window to update itself with new data.

Variables are defined as follows:

```
Display *d;
Window w;
XEvent exppp;
```

The window is started with the following code:

```
XEvent e;

d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
if (d == NULL) 
  return 0;

s = DefaultScreen(d);
w = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 10, 10, 200, 800, 1,
                        BlackPixel(d, s), WhitePixel(d, s));
XSelectInput(d, w, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
XMapWindow(d, w);

while (1) {
  XNextEvent(d, &e);
  if (e.type == Expose || e.type == KeyPress) {
    // redraw routine goes here
  }
}
```

What I was attempting to use to get the window to redraw is a function that can be called by another thread:

```
void graphical_out::redraw()
{
  exppp.type = Expose;
  XSendEvent(d, w, false, Expose, &exppp);
}
```

And the window only updates itself when it is re-sized or receives a key-press. This seems a bit like a newbie question but Google has failed me on this one. Any suggestions to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your arguments to `XSendEvent` are wrong. You need to pass the mask (`ExposureMask`), not the event type.
2. `exppp.xexpose.window = w;` is mandatory (the window argument of `XSendEvent` is *not* the window of the `XEvent` structure).
3. Clean the event before sending it: `memset(&exppp, 0, sizeof(exppp));`, just in case.
4. Xlib is not thread-safe and calling its functions from more than one thread *may* be dangerous.

**UPDATE** In a multithreaded program one needs to call `XFlush` here and there (though multithreading is never guaranteed to work with Xlib).

This code works for me:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <memory.h>

Display *d;
Window w;
int s;

void* tp (void* q)
{
    XEvent exppp;

    while (1)
    {
        sleep (3);
        printf ("Sending event of type Expose\n");
        memset(&exppp, 0, sizeof(exppp));
        exppp.type = Expose;
        exppp.xexpose.window = w;
        XSendEvent(d,w,False,ExposureMask,&exppp);
        XFlush(d);
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main ()
{
    XEvent e;
    pthread_t thread;

    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d == NULL)
        return 0;

    s = DefaultScreen(d);
    w = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 10, 10, 200, 800, 1,
                            BlackPixel(d, s), WhitePixel(d, s));
    XSelectInput(d, w, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
    XMapWindow(d, w);

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, tp, NULL);

    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(d, &e);
        if (e.type == Expose) {
            printf ("Got Expose event%s\n", e.xexpose.send_event ? " (SendEvent)" : "");
        }
        else if (e.type == KeyPress) {
            printf ("Got KeyPress event%s\n", e.xkey.send_event ? " (SendEvent)" : "");
        }
    }
}
```

It might work for you, or it might bomb. Xlib is not thread safe, use at your own risk.

Comment: ok tried adding that, still no joy. is there something else I'm missing or is this just a bad way to go about this ?

Comment: In the multithreaded setting you probably have to add a call to `XFlush` after each `XSendEvent`. See the code in the updated answer.

Comment: many thanks, got it to work. For some reason it works stably if the two threads both call XOpenDisplay and use separate display* structures. with both using the same display* d it gave some stability problems